# Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt, esp8266, mosca

I am trying to establish MQTT communication with my local MQTT server on my pc (node.js, express, Mosca) and Esp8266.

esp8286 is not connecting with my server, the error is

> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds

Can't connect to Broker.

Here is Node js code:

```
var moscaSettings = {
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 1883,
  http: {
      port: 8002,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      static: './mqtt/',
      bundle: true,
  },
};

var server = new mosca.Server(moscaSettings);

// var server = new mosca.Server({
//     host: '192.168.1.75'

//   });

  server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    console.log('client connected', client.id);
  });

  server.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
    console.log('client disconnected', client.id);
  });

  server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
    console.log(packet);
  });

  server.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
    console.log('subscribed: ' + client.id);
  });

  server.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
    console.log('unsubscribed: ' + client.id);
  });

  var ledCommand = '1';

  setInterval(function() {
    ledCommand = (ledCommand === '1') ? '1' : '0';
    server.publish({topic: '1/1/1', payload: ledCommand});
  }, 8000);



  server.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Mosca server is up and running');
    console.log("MQTT server is ready on port %s", moscaSettings.port);
    console.log("HTTP Server is ready on pott %s", moscaSettings.http.port);
  });

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
});
```

and here is Esp8266 code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

// Change the credentials below, so your ESP8266 connects to your router
const char* ssid = "AP1";
const char* password = "API@786_22#";


const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.75";
const char* clientname = "ESP-01-CLIENT1234";

//const int mqttPort = 3000;

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
// for data store intilization 

int address = 10;
int s1=11;
int s2=12;
char arrayToStore1[10];
char arrayToStore2[10];
char arrayToStore[10]; 


// Connect an LED to each GPIO of your ESP8266
const int ledGPIO2 = D2;
const int ledGPIO3 = D3;

// Don't change the function below. This functions connects your ESP8266 to your router
void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("WiFi connected - ESP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

// This functions is executed when some device publishes a message to a topic that your ESP8266 is subscribed to
// Change the function below to add logic to your program, so when a device publishes a message to a topic that 
// your ESP8266 is subscribed you can actually do something
void callback(String topic, byte* message, unsigned int length) {
  pinMode(ledGPIO3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledGPIO2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.print("Message arrived on topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print(". Message: ");
  String messageTemp;

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)message[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)message[i];
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Feel free to add more if statements to control more GPIOs with MQTT

  // If a message is received on the topic home/office/esp1/gpio2, you check if the message is either 1 or 0. Turns the ESP GPIO according to the message
  if(topic=="1/1/1" || topic=="1/1"){
    topic.toCharArray(arrayToStore, topic.length()+1);
      EEPROM.begin(512);
      EEPROM.put(address, arrayToStore);
      EEPROM.commit();
      Serial.println(arrayToStore);
      Serial.print("Changing GPIO 4 for 1 ");
      if(messageTemp == "1"){
        digitalWrite(ledGPIO2, LOW);
        messageTemp.toCharArray(arrayToStore1, messageTemp.length()+1);
         EEPROM.put(s1, arrayToStore1);
         EEPROM.commit();
        Serial.print("On");
      }
      else if(messageTemp == "0"){
         Serial.print("Changing GPIO 4 for 0 ");
        digitalWrite(ledGPIO2, HIGH);
        Serial.print("Off");
      }
  }
  if(topic=="1/1/2" || topic=="1/1"){
      Serial.print("Changing GPIO 5 to ");
      if(messageTemp == "1"){
        digitalWrite(ledGPIO3, HIGH);
        Serial.print("On");
      }
      else if(messageTemp == "0"){
        digitalWrite(ledGPIO3, LOW);
        Serial.print("Off");
      }
  }
  Serial.println();
}

// This functions reconnects your ESP8266 to your MQTT broker
// Change the function below if you want to subscribe to more topics with your ESP8266 
void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientname,"usman.jamil","Code@123")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      //client.publish("presence", "hello from mqtt");
       client.subscribe("1/1/1");
      client.subscribe("1/1");
      client.subscribe("1/1/2");
      // ... and resubscribe
      //client.subscribe("tempfeed");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

// The setup function sets your ESP GPIOs to Outputs, starts the serial communication at a baud rate of 115200
// Sets your mqtt broker and sets the callback function
// The callback function is what receives messages and actually controls the LEDs
void setup() {
 // client.setCallback(callback);

  // pinMode(ledGPIO2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
   EEPROM.begin(512);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);    //1883
  client.setCallback(callback);
  Serial.println("void setup runnning here ");
  Serial.println("value saved in eeprom ");
  EEPROM.get(s1, arrayToStore1); 
  Serial.println(arrayToStore1);
  //if(arrayToStore=="1/1/1")

  if (strcmp(arrayToStore1, "1") == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("value  in eeprom ");
    //digitalWrite(ledGPIO2, HIGH);
    pinMode(ledGPIO2, OUTPUT); 
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("value not saved in eeprom ");
      // digitalWrite(ledGPIO2, HIGH);
      }


}

// For this project, you don't need to change anything in the loop function. 
// Basically it ensures that you ESP is connected to your broker
void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  if(!client.loop())
     /*
     YOU  NEED TO CHANGE THIS NEXT LINE, IF YOU'RE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH MQTT MULTIPLE CONNECTIONS
     To change the ESP device ID, you will have to give a unique name to the ESP8266.
     Here's how it looks like now:
       client.connect("ESP8266Client");
     If you want more devices connected to the MQTT broker, you can do it like this:
       client.connect("ESPOffice");
     Then, for the other ESP:
       client.connect("ESPGarage");
      That should solve your MQTT multiple connections problem

     THE SECTION IN recionnect() function should match your device name
    */
    client.connect(clientname);
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the node.js script? Is there a firewall between the client and the server?

Comment: @Adrian W Output :{ topic: '1/1/1',
  payload: '1',
  messageId: 'GWmX0SB',
  qos: undefined,
  retain: undefined }

Comment: So, it seems the server never received `ready`? In that case I would have expected the output of the function registered with `server.on('ready', ...)`

Comment: It seems a network problem, try to login to your MQTT server from a mobile application for smartphone and check, or check with another device if the port is open and correctly reachable within the network.